# Incorrect values when converting a column in a data frame to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

While trying to convert `Latitude` and `Longitude` in a data frame using `as.numeric`,  which in their original form look like:

```
Latitude    Longitude
 12.05N      77.26E
```

I am getting incorrect values. So, I try to replace `N` in the latitude and `E` in the longitude in the following way:

```
dframe$Latitude  = as.numeric(dframe$Latitude)

dframe$Longitude  = as.numeric(dframe$Longitude)
```

The final output is `79` in the longitude and `4` in the latitude. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, converting a character object to numeric that isn't a perfectly good number results in `NA`:

```
> Z = c("23.2N","12.4N")
> as.numeric(Z)
[1] NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

So you must have something else, I suspect its a `factor`:

```
> Z = factor(c("23.2N","12.4N"))
> as.numeric(Z)
[1] 2 1
```

The numeric value of a factor is an index into the number of different values in the factor - they are intended for categorical data. I suspect you may have read the data in using `read.csv` and not looked at the `stringsAsFactors` option. Anyway. You can convert factors to character to get the values you see rather than the underlying index number:

```
> Z = factor(c("23.2N","12.4N"))
> as.numeric(as.character(Z))
[1] NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Now we get the `NA` because of the `"N"` messing up the number format, so we can substitute all `"N"` with nothing and convert:

```
> as.numeric(gsub("N","",as.character(Z)))
[1] 23.2 12.4
```

giving you the numbers.

Comment: Or something like this: `gsub("[A-Z]", "", as.character(Z))`

Comment: That will replace all letters. I prefer to do just the minimum amount of processing that will fix your expected problem. For example, if all data should be North and you replace all letters, anything mistakenly South will become valid. Replace only N and you can trap South data as errors. But you should validate as well. And check. Twice.